# %windir% in Python?

Tags: python, windows

How can I do something like

```
if sys.argv[0] != '%windir%\\blabla.exe'
```

I'm having no success at all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import os
if sys.argv[0] != os.path.join(os.environ['WINDIR'],'blalah.exe'):
```

Answer (score 4):

This should illustrate how to get the location of Windows:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['windir']
'C:\\Windows'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if sys.argv[0] != '%windir%\\blabla.exe'
```

What are you trying to do here?

`argv[0]` is, generally, the filename of the script you are invoking. It would seem unlikely to be `blabla.exe`, unless you're using some packaging tool to compile yourself into an EXE. If you want to look at the first argument passed to the script, see `sys.argv[1]`.

Also, when you use an `%EnvironmentVariable%` from the console, the Windows shell will replace the variable name with its content. So when you type `myscript.py %windir%\blabla.exe`, Windows will replace that with `myscript.py C:\Windows\blabla.exe` (or similar) before your script gets a look in, and your comparison will fail because the variable name is no longer there.

You can use `os.path.expandvars` to do the same replacement to your own strings (or just read `os.environ` yourself). You may also want to absolutize the path so you can compare the real effective path without having to worry about relative paths:

```
blapath= os.path.expandvars(r'%WinDir%\blabla.exe')
if os.path.abspath(sys.argv[1])==os.path.abspath(blapath):
    ...
```

In this case, you could also consider `os.path.normcase`​ing both paths, to allow for Windows's case-insensitivity.

Comment: ... unless he's packaging his script as an exe AND putting the result into the %windir% directory (perish the thought). One would hope that his condition always evaluates to False :-) ... otherwise +1 for an answer that addresses all the issues.

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```
if sys.argv[0] != os.environ.get("windir")
```

That should do it for you.  Just add your `blabla.exe` on the end of that.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`os.environ`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.environ) to get the value of the environment variable, and string interpolation to put it with the rest of the string:

```
execfile = r'%s\blabla.exe' % (os.environ['windir'],)

if sys.argv[0] != execfile:
   ....
```

Comment: -1 ALWAYS use os.path.join() to assemble paths; it saves you from having to think: oh I'm on Windows so the separator is backslash and oh whoops better put that pesky little `r` at the start of the string constant